# Find entities for a list of matching PartitionKeys in one query without doing foreach

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-table-storage

I have a list of partition keys say List partitionIds.
I want to query the Azure table storage to get all the entities like :

```
var query = (from result in dataServiceContext.CreateQuery<SampleEntity>
                         where lstPartitionKeys.Contains(result.PartitionKey)
                         select result);
return query.TryToList();
```

But this doesn't works for me and gives no result records.
Need help if there is any problem with this way of accessing the records in Azure table storage.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're using `Contains` LINQ operator which is not supported by Azure Table service.

For a list of query operators supported by Azure Table Service, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135725.aspx.

Comment: Thanks @gaurav its clear to me now. Do you have any other workaround to fulfill my purpose. Right now I can't think of any?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of what you're trying to do? I could see 2 possible things you are trying to do: 1) Find entities for a list of matching PartitionKeys or 2) Find entities which contains a string in PartitionKey value.

Comment: Yes the first one only i.e Find entities for a list of matching PartitionKeys.
I don't want to do foreach for each partition key and then get each record and put it in a new List.

Comment: You could perform each of the queries in a different thread using something like TPL and then merge the results.